# how to create spf record as spf.example.com

Tags: dns, spf

usually, we get an SPF record in the form of `spf.thirdpartyexample.com` now if we install any email server we create an SPF record with `ip:xx.xx.xxx.x` [reference link from validity](https://www.validity.com/blog/how-to-build-your-spf-record-in-5-simple-steps/#:%7E:text=SPF%20authenticates%20a%20sender%E2%80%99s%20identity%20by%20comparing%20the,IP%20addresses%20that%20are%20authorized%20to%20send%20mail.)

```
v=spf1 -mx -ptr include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net -all
```

so my question is :

how to create an SPF record as `spf.example.com` for our own server in the same way we get from a third-party vendor?

Comment: this is off-topic here. you should ask on [sf] or [su]. this place is for programming related questions not config and setup.

Comment: please transfer it to that place @user3788685

Comment: Hiya sorry I can't personally transfer it (not enough credits) but you should be able to yourself, or worst case delete this question and just re-ask it there. It won't cost you any credits. When you get a moment you should also have a look at the [help]

Comment: @user3788685 then let it stay here because two tags DNS and mail-server both exist here and both of them are related to this question, else mod would react if it is irrelevant for this SOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to "authorize" your own domain/s in your Bind/dns?
If, then you should have

```
yourdomain.tld.             IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ~all"
```

in your bind zone configuration file
v=spf1 tells it's a spf record
"a" tells that "yourdomain.tld" IP is allowed to send mail from yourdomain.tld
"mx" tells that the mx server IP of yourdomain.tld is allowed to send mail
"~all" tells that SPF queries that do not match any other mechanism will return “softfail”. Messages that are not sent from an approved server (the server with ip [www.xxx.yyy.zzz](http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz) = the ip of the mail server yourdomain.tld = "a". The server with ip aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd = the ip of the mx record of yourdomain.tld = "mx") should still be accepted but may be subjected to greater scrutiny...
So, if your dns record is like

```
yourdomain.tld.        IN      A       aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
mail.yourdomain.tld.   IN      A       www.xxx.yyy.zzz
yourdomain.tld.        IN      MX      10      mail.yourdomain.tld.
```

the SPF tells that

1. if the mail is sent from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd (the "a") that's ok
2. if the mail is sent from [www.xxx.yyy.zzz](http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz) (the "mx") that's ok